# How to check whether remoter server support TLS 1.3

Tags: ssl, centos7

I am using CentOS 7. 
I want to check whether remote web server supports TLS1.3 or not.

I have tried through nmap but till date, nmap (version 7.80) doesn’t supports TLS1.3

Is there an easy way to check for that?

Comment: Wouldn't openssl allow you to do that?

Comment: curl https://<server>/ --verbose [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388689/how-to-test-if-a-remote-server-support-tls1-2-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am pretty sure openssl ([you need at least version 1.1.1](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-openssl-on-centos-7/)) is able to do this.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -tls1_3
```

See https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/OpenSSL_test_TLSv1.3_connection_with_s_client.html as well.

Comment: This openssl command is giving too much data. This i have to use in my script, so I want a easiest way to find out the tls1.3 support without too much grep/sed.

Comment: Kind of unfair to move the goalposts on the question, @GauravKansal. You didn't specify that restriction in your question. Now Tony Stark has the question answered, and has the most upvotes, but isn't selected as the answer...

Answer (score 3):

Openssl s_client -connect  ip:port  -tls1_3

It can help....

Comment: I get: unknown option -tls1_3